# Can't find the error :/

Tags: php, database, mysqli, error-handling, syntax

Got a table with client data. Trying to incorporate an edit function. Currently, the table has a `<a href>` for the "edit" link.

```
        <tr>

            <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>

        </tr>
        <?php while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><a href="crud/update.php?id='.$r['id'].'">Edit</a></td>
            <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
             </tr>

   function deleteme(delid)
  { if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
    window.location.href='crud/delete.php';
   }
 } 
 </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

note that:

```
$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);
```

I hoped to take the user to the crud/update.php which starts as:

```
<?php
 error_reporting();
   require_once('connect.php');
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $SelSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE id=$id";
   $res = mysqli_query($connection, $SelSql);
   $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
 $name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
  //and other credentials 

  $UpdateSql = "UPDATE `contact` SET Name='$name', Company='$comp', 
 Title='$title', Phone='$phone', Email='$email', Address='$location' WHERE id=$id";
```

Pulling my hair out because I can't find why I get an error every time I press the "edit" link.

Cheers guys.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I think you should check for `$_GET` rather than `$_POST` in the `if()`, because you are directing to `crud/update.php` via `<a>` and not by submitting a form

Comment: Error 404 page not found

Comment: you are mixing HTML and PHP , link should be : `<a href="crud/update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>`

Comment: @kerrysun does the answer resolve your query? if so then please accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting 404 is that you did not have proper link.

You have mixed HTML and PHP on line

```
<a href="crud/update.php?id='.$r['id'].'">Edit</a>
```

It should be:

```
<a href="crud/update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a>
```